# AngularJS validate table row with update buttons on each row

Tags: angularjs

I am building a table using angular ng-repeat.  I need to have the ability to update or delete each row independently and thus need to validate each row independently.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items" >
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.AccountNumber" ng-maxlength="model.validation.maxAccountLength" /></td>
    <td><select ng-model="item.OriginCountry" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.OriginCountries"></select></td>
    <td><select ng-model="item.DestinationCountry" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.DestinationCountries"></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.Zone" ng-maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="updateItem(item)" class="btn btn-warning" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to validate each row idependently

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the row contents with forms and add name attributes to your inputs/selects

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items" >
<td>
 <form name="form">     
 <input name="account_number" type="text" ng-model="item.AccountNumber" ng-maxlength="model.validation.maxAccountLength" /></td>
<td>name="origin" ng-model="item.OriginCountry" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.OriginCountries"></select></td>
<td><select name="destination" ng-model="item.DestinationCountry" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.DestinationCountries"></select></td>
<td><input name="zone" type="text" ng-model="item.Zone" ng-maxlength="4" /></td>
<td><button type="button" ng-click="updateItem(item)" class="btn btn-warning" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>
<td><button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
 </form>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Now you can use the FormController state like `form.$submitted` or `form.zone.$touched`

(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: I worked around it using min/maxlength and a directive for only allowing numeric input.